# How can I set Alternate row color in RadGridview in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik

How can I set Alternate row color in RadGridview in silverlight

Comment: use logic with if (rowNumber%2==0)

Comment: see [this link](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radgridview-rows-alternating-rows.html)

Comment: Woops, I just saw your comment after posting the answer. +1 for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're after is `UseAlternateRowStyle` & `AlternateRowStyle` I believe. I've never used telerik's controls myself but I found an example on telerik's forums that will probably help:

Resource Section:

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewAlternateRowStyle" TargetType="Telerik_Windows_Controls_GridView:GridViewRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Controls Section:

```
<telerikGridView:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AlternateRowStyle="{StaticResource GridViewAlternateRowStyle}" AlternationCount="2"/>
```

Link to original telerik forum post [Here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/alternaterowstyle-and-rowdetails.aspx) with complete project.

Comment: <telerik:RadGridView Name="radPortGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternateRowBackground="#BDEDFF" AlternationCount="2" />

Comment: @ Anil.It needs to use two properties Alternaterowbackground and AlternateCount

Comment: Thanks for that update. I'll keep it in mind for next time. I've incorporated your correction into original post for others to avoid a head scratching moment. :)